# SQLite - How to get occurrence of all characters in String

Tags: database, string, sqlite, char, character

Is there a possibility in SQLite to extract all letters from a string and count their occrrences?
A example for a string will look like this: "This is a example".

The solution should look like this:

### Character ->  Occurrence

T->(1x),h->(1x),i->(2x),s->(2x),a->(2x),e->(2x),x->(1x),m->(1x),l->(1x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a recursive `CTE`:

```
with
  recursive cte as (
    select 1 pos, substr('This is an example', 1, 1) letter
    union all
    select pos + 1, substr('This is an example', pos + 1, 1)
    from cte
    where pos < length('This is an example')
   ),
   letters as (select distinct letter from cte where letter <> ' ')
select 
  letter, 
  length('This is an example') - length(replace('This is an example', letter, '')) counter
from letters
```

or:

```
with
  recursive cte as (
    select 1 pos, substr('This is an example', 1, 1) letter
    union all
    select pos + 1, substr('This is an example', pos + 1, 1)
    from cte
    where pos < length('This is an example')
   )
select 
  letter, 
  count(*) counter
from cte
where letter <> ' '
group by letter
```

For the case of a column in a table:

```
create table tablename(id int, col text);

insert into tablename(id, col) values
(1, 'This is an example'),
(2, 'Another one'),
(3, 'XY');

with
  recursive cte as (
    select id, col, 1 pos, substr(col, 1, 1) letter
    from tablename
    union all
    select id, col, pos + 1, substr(col, pos + 1, 1)
    from cte
    where pos < length(col)
   )
select 
  id, col, 
  letter, 
  count(*) counter
from cte
where letter <> ' '
group by id, letter;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9WAitbTogqrKNy6V5H5rY7/0).

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Is there also a solution for iterating this over a column of strings instead of the example string?